# Java Inheritance Constraints

Tags: c#, java, inheritance, type-constraints

I am trying to port some code I wrote in C# to Java, but do not know all of the Java syntax yet.  I also have no idea what this type of thing is called, so it is harder to search..I am calling it "inheritance constraints."

Basically, is there a java equivalent to this C# code:

```
public abstract class MyObj<T> where T : MyObj<T>, new()
{

}
```

Thanks.

---

Edit:

Is there any way to do this:

```
public abstract class MyObj<T extends MyObj<T>> {
    public abstract String GetName();

    public virtual void Test() {
          T t = new T();                // Somehow instantiate T to call GetName()?
          String name = t.GetName();
    }
}
```

Comment: For the second part, are you wanting to instantiate an actual T object, or a MyObj object?

Comment: @LJ2 I need to instantiate a T object (which is required to be a MyObj object.  I need it to be "T" because the implementation of GetName() will be different for each T

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a good answer for you, I'm more curious as to what the purpose of your construct is here... if T extends MyObj, then simply implementing the getName() method in the generic subclass and calling `String name = getName()` in the MyObj test() method will (I think) give you the desired functionality... in this case, you DO need to implement and instantiate a specific T, in a context above these this abstract class, in order to run the MyObj.test() method... for instance, you would code and instantiate a subclass (SomeObj 'so', for instance), and call `so.test()`

Comment: You lost me a little, but essentially the client will want to do something like this:

`MyObj<MySubObj1> m = new MySubObj1();
m.Test();`

The Test() method needs a way to call the GetName() method that is defined in the MySubObj1 class (as opposed to the MySubObj2 class.)

As an example, think of an ORM framework. You may want to define an abstract "DatabaseTable" class that implements various SQL queries.  In order to construct the queries, it may have to call a "GetColumns()" function that returns the column names specific to each type of "DatabaseTable"

Comment: Yeah, that is essentially what I was saying... I'll provide an answer below to elaborate (even though the question has already been answered.)

Comment: Something bounded on itself like `class MyObj<T extends MyObj<T>>` is almost never useful in Java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not quite. There's this:

```
public abstract class MyObj<T extends MyObj<T>>
```

but there's no equivalent to the `new()` constraint.

EDIT: To create an instance of `T`, you'll need the appropriate `Class<T>` - otherwise *type erasure* will byte you.

Typically you'd add this as a constructor parameter:

```
public MyObj(Class<T> clazz) {
    // This can throw all kinds of things, which you need to catch here or
    // propagate.
    T t = clazz.newInstance(); 
}
```

Comment: Hmm...Thank you.  So is there any way to instantiate T? (See the edit that I made)

Comment: Or alternatively: (I just thought of this): Can you have static abstract methods in Java? I know this is not possible in C#, unfortunately.

Comment: @Eric: No, and for the same reason: static methods aren't polymorphic. Polymorphism occurs based on the execution-time type of an *instance*. Will edit my answer to explain about instantiating `T`.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your comment above, you're looking for the following construct:

An `interface` with which you will interact with MyObj objects in code... you will be calling the test() method (standard style in Java is camelcase methods, capitalized classes/interfaces)

```
public interface IMyObj {
    public void test();
}
```

You will want the abstract superclass... for the example that you've chosen, you don't NEED to specify any genericism, although you absolutely can if the actual implementation is more reliant on type safety... this class should implement the IMyObj interface:

```
public abstract class MyObj implements IMyObj {

    String name;

    public abstract String getName();

    public void test() {
        name = getName();
    }
}
```

From here you would write your subclasses to MyObj...

```
public class MySubObj1 extends MyObj {
    public String getName() { return "MySubObj1"; }
}

public class MySubObj2 extends MyObj {
    public String getName() { return "MySubObj2"; }
}
```

Then you safely and correctly use the following snippet in another class:

```
IMyObj obj = new MySubObj1();
obj.test();
```

The key is that you use interfaces to hide the implementation, and use abstract classes to hold common code that subclasses will utilize in their implementations.

Hope this helps!